tensorflow not detecting gpu in a conda environment on ubuntu 22.04
Ubuntu : 22.04
rtx 3070ti notebook + i7 12700
conda 24.1.2
tensorflow 2.16.1
Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
I tried pip install tensorflow[and cuda] like it says on the website,had multiple issue
my-user@my-comp:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-04-09 17:06:49.632664: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-04-09 17:06:49.916292: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-09 17:06:50.566675: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-04-09 17:06:51.314772: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-04-09 17:06:51.327971: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]


redone it in anaconda pip install tensorflow[and cuda] same issues, and thenconda install tensorflow[and-cuda]in environment TF, it's just not returning the gpu
(TF) my-user@my-comp:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-04-09 16:53:36.841997: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
[]



Hi@physics_freak963, Make sure that CUDA and cuDNN are properly installed on your system and that the paths are correctly set. TensorFlow requires specific versions of CUDA and cuDNN, so ensure that you have installed compatible versions.Update your Conda environment to ensure that all packages are up to date. You can do this by running conda update --all within your Conda environment.Make sure that your GPU is recognized by your system. You can check this by running the following command:nvidia-smi
